# How do you deploy text changes to iOS app without a deploy?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, app-store, google-play-developer-api

This is to allow localization and quick changes of text within app, without requiring an app redeploy to App Store or Google Play
Context: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14504556

Comment: I don't know if it's possible doing that using native apps, but it's possible to do it in Ionic framework for hybrid mobile apps (Ionic live deploy)

Answer (score 0):

I usually dont use it, but you can have an easy updater, which checks (once a day / week / month) for new string-files on your server and downloads them. You should load the strings in this case from your own file.

Answer (score 0):

A dedicated service to allow for collaborative localization and text updates without client releases is [Lokalise](http://lokalize.co).

[lokalise.co](http://lokalize.co)

I haven't used it but it looks to be promising.